# Does UV Light Kill the Volatiles?

Tags: dying-light

We have a pocket UV light. So, does that kill the volatiles if we hold it on them enough?

I'm at the entrance of the tunnel, so if I get inside, there is the dark area. I can cook them with my UV light on the bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No the uv light just make the nights stop for a while so you can keep running and build distance. However so longer you aim them with the uv light, the longer they'll stay away from you.
After the uv light effect stopped, they'll start to chase you again.

I've to say that there're two kind of "nights".

First you got the Volatiles who you find in single player.
[image: Volatiles]

Second are the Night Hunter who are multiplayer.
[image: Night Hunter]

Both of them got the uv light weakness but can't be killed with it.

Comment: Also note that the UV light can't be on indefinitely. If you hold it on long enough, it will go out (and make the sound of a filament breaking) and it will be on cooldown for a bit until you can use it again.